# .prop, .attr not working when trying to disable asp:CheckBox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, checkbox, prop

I have a bunch of asp:checkboxs. Most of them have a class of "restricted" and all of them have clientIdMode='static'. I have a separate checkbox with id='other'. When this box is clicked, I want the boxes with class='restricted' to be disabled. Problem is I can't get it to work in Firefox or Chrome. I've found a bunch of related questions on the net but no real answers.

```
$('#other').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".restricted").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $(".restricted").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

I've tried using combinations of .prop, .attr, ("disabled", true), and ("disabled", "disabled") but I can't get it to work outside IE.

EDIT: Here is some html as well:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Accessories</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="restricted" />
            <label for="cb1">VAL 1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbP2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="restricted" />
            <label for="cb2">VAL 2</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cb3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="restricted" />
            <label for="cbPickupInside">VAL 3</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cb4" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="restricted" />
            <label for="cb4">Value 4</label>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

And the checkbox that when clicked should disable the other:

```
<fieldset>
<ol>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbG" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <label for="cbG">VAL G</label>
    </li>
```

Comment: if you're using asp:checkbox, thats not the id, asp converts the ID into this massive string. i would use a class instead.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey Usually "ct100" or something similar is added as a prefix. But it's pretty unreliable, imo.

Comment: haha unreliable indeed, ive seen it do some crazy crazy stuff. either make it an html textbox and give it the `runat="server"` to make it work with ASP, or make it a class.

Comment: I thought ClientIDMode='Static' kept the id the same...it's showing me the checkbox id='other' if I inspect the checkbox in browser. The name does get the added prefix.

Comment: I've fiddled your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pyQ2x/ -- Seems to be working in IE9 and Chrome...

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey That's only true if you're using containers, such as a repeater or master page...

Comment: @DouglasBubbletrousers Where is the checkbox with the id "other"?

Comment: @DouglasBubbletrousers What version of jQuery are you using and do you have the `.click()` method inside of a `$(document).ready(function () {});`?

Comment: It is inside $(document).ready. Looks like I'm using jquery-1.7.1.

Comment: @DouglasBubbletrousers So where's the checkbox with the `id` of "other"? I see the checkbox with an `id` of "cbG", but that's not "other".

Comment: Oops. id='cbG' is actually id='other'. I was changing some variables around for posting purposes and forgot to change that one to other.

Comment: @DouglasBubbletrousers Ahh okay. Well try this: `if (this.checked) {` instead of your first if statement, and then try `$(".restricted").prop("disabled", true);` instead of trying to set the property's value as "disabled". Not sure if it'll fix anything, but worth a shot - it's how I would've done it. Also, try putting `alert` or `console.log` statements inside the `if` and `else` blocks to see if the correct thing is at least being run.

Comment: I've tried all that. It's definitely hitting inside the if/else block. It's weird, usually IE is the fickle browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#other').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".restricted input").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else {
            $(".restricted input").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
```

I fixed it by adding the input selector after the class selector. The span around the input is what actually had the class, so I guess IE finds the span and runs the code against the input. Chrome and Firefox must stop at the span.

Answer (score -1):

If this is an asp checkbox, target like so:

```
$("#<%=other.ClientID %>").click(function() {
    //code here
});
```

Change your checkbox class from

```
CssClass="restricted"
```

To

```
class="restricted"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fix anything. Still works in IE, but not in Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: Can you try removing the clientidmode=static and trying selecting like above?

Comment: Still no dice. After changing CssClass to class it still works in IE, but not in the other two.